# Best Way to Leverage Custom Post Type Related Content and Consider SEO

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, urls, seo

I'm doing a real estate project for a client.  I've created a custom post type called "communities" to list new construction communities in her area.

I also want to have deeper sub pages but I would like to keep the URL structure in line with: /communities/tall-pines-development to show something along the lines of: /communities/tall-pines-development/site-plan, /layouts, /clubhouse, etc.

I see that child pages is one consideration but I'm not quite sure how to implement them on a custom post type.

Since I already am in a custom post type I'm not sure how to go deeper and keep the logical structure of the URL and enable something like breadcrumbs which are also great for SEO.

Hope that makes sense.  I was thinking about building a jQuery tabbed navigation on the single-communities page template, but for SEO purposes I think separate pages would be more optimal.

Was thinking taxonomies at first, but how would I show the additional content I need including a featured image, image(s) and content?

Hope that makes sense.  Burning the midnight oil and the brain is slowing down. Just isn't coming to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Using custom post type is great... From an SEO point of view the only

thing you need to think of when talking about the URL is that it would

"Tell a story" and wont have any ->> & symbols in it...**

What you should have is the main "custom post type page", then the taxomonies
inside it then the posts / singles...

That means you should have three additional files in your theme structure

1. CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME-page.php
2. single-CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME.php
3. taxonomy.php

---

**EXAMPLE:**
i have a jewelry site where each jewelry type has a custom post type... 
This example would use engagement rings...

*Here is my custom post type page Url:*
http://www.example.com/?engagement_cat

*Here is my taxonomy Url:*
http://www.example.com/?engagement_cat=prestige

*Here is my product Url:*
http://www.example.com/?engagement_ring=18k-gold-ladies-engagement-ring

[image]

.
In my (humble) opinion this is gr8 since its clear, short & tell's a story
to the search engine while keeping the desired keyword in the URL...

You can achive this by simply using  'rewrite' => true, When registering a taxonomy... the rest is automated by wordpress.

---

**As far as taxonomies "pages"...**
its all a matter of showing as much related information as possible right?
so why not just do a check for the "post type" that lead to that taxonomy
and design the page to fit that information...

**Here is an example:**

```
global $wp_query;
$term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$taxomonyTitle = $term->name;

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

        if ($post_type == 'engagement_ring') {
            echo 'Engagement Rings Stuff here'
        } elseif ($post_type == 'wedding_ring') {
            echo 'Wedding Rings Stuff here'
        } elseif ($post_type == 'pendants') {       
            echo 'Pendatns Stuff here'
        } elseif ($post_type == 'earrings') {
            echo 'Earrings Stuff here'
        } elseif ($post_type == 'bracelets') {
            echo 'Bracelets Stuff here'         
        }
```

.
Now you got the taxonomy title and the post type and you can assign variables..
get meta box values and so on..

Hope this helps,
Sagive SEO